Most efficient way to calculate first k left singular vectors (not values) on GPU
I’m working with big rectangular $n\times m$ matrix $A$ and would like to calculate the first $k$ dominant left singular vectors. In other words I would like to find $U_k$ which comes from the k-rank approximation $A_k=U_kS_kV_k^\dagger$. I'm interested in doing so efficiently on the GPU so ideally using QR instead of any SVD because GPU speeds QR up a lot more. A basic approach I've found is to do block SVD power method. Are there any more sophisticated approaches?
